# Prevent full page from flashing before showing a tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pug

Currently I am using the [twitter bootstrap tabs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) on a page with the following code.  I added a bit of javascript/jquery to push hash tags in the url, so I can actually link to a tab.  This works fine, but the when I load the first tab I see the whole page and then I am quickly shown just the first tab.  Now, if I click tabs on the page everything works nicely and I am not shown the whole page again.  This flash of data is annoying to say the least.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

[Jade Template Code](http://jade-lang.com/), compiles down to standard HTML

```
    div(class="tabbable")
      ul(id="myTab", class="nav nav-tabs")
        li
          a(href="#surveyEditData", data-toggle="tab") Survey
        li
          a(href="#surveyEditQuestions", data-toggle="tab") Questions
        ...etc...
```

JavaScript code:

```
    $(function(){
      // Function to activate the tab
      function activateTab() {
        var activeTab = $('[href=' + window.location.hash.replace('/', '') + ']');
        activeTab && activeTab.tab('show');
      }

      // Trigger when the page loads
      activateTab();
    });
```

Comment: jquery load() function can do the trick..

Comment: I took a look at the documentation and tried a few things, could you give an example or more direction?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the delay in the HTML being rendered before the Javascript is done executing.

To fix this, you need to put an initial CSS style such as  fade or hide to all the other tabs, except the first one.

CSS rules are executed immediately during rendering, so there will be no delay for these rules.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't tried editing the code yet, but this makes sense and should fix my problem.  Thank you so much!